# Is it harmful to put any comment as a first thing in CSSfile?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Is it harmful to put anything as a comment as a first thing in a CSS file? Can it cause any problem in any browser or does it have no cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see how this could be harmful.

If you specify an `@encoding`, it must be in the first line [(Source)](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset). Otherwise, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, no it does not, and it wont have any impact on browser parsing.

Comment: OK. now I forgot where but i read somewhere 2-3 yrs ago "W3c validator doesn't like comment as a first thing" but may now it's not a problem

Comment: You may be confusing HTML (Where the doctype should be the 1st thing) and CSS.